# Why are My JPG and PNG Files Accessible Despite Nginx Access Restriction?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am running a Nginx for a website. And I set the config to protect some folders.

```
location ~ /(data|conf|bin|inc|vendor)/ 
{       deny all;     }
```

I reload the Nginx and looks it works. It will return '403 Forbidden' when I try to load some txt file from these folders from browser.
But I notice, the jpg and png files can still be accessed.
For example, https://www.example.com/data/file.txt can be denied, but https://www.example.com/data/photo.jpg can be load.

I tried other file type, ppt/exls/pdf, all be denied,except image type.

Here is my whole nginx file, just change url to example.com.

```
server
{
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name www.example.com example.com;
index index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.htm default.html;
root /www/wwwroot/www.example.com;

    #error_page 404/404.html;
    #HTTP_TO_HTTPS_START
    if ($server_port !~ 443){
        rewrite ^(/.*)$ https://$host$1 permanent;
    }
    #HTTP_TO_HTTPS_END
    ssl_certificate    /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    error_page 497  https://$host$request_uri;
    
    #SSL-END
    
    #error_page 404 /404.html;
    #error_page 502 /502.html;
    #ERROR-PAGE-END
    
    
    include enable-php-74.conf;
    #PHP-INFO-END
    
    
    include /www/server/panel/vhost/rewrite/www.example.com.conf;
    #REWRITE-END
    
    
    location ~ ^/(\.user.ini|\.htaccess|\.git|\.env|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README.md)
    {
        return 404;
    }
    
    
    location ~ \.well-known{
        allow all;
    }
    
    
    if ( $uri ~ "^/\.well-known/.*\.(php|jsp|py|js|css|lua|ts|go|zip|tar\.gz|rar|7z|sql|bak)$" ) {
        return 403;
    }
    
    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
    {
        expires      30d;
        error_log /dev/null;
        access_log /dev/null;
    }
    
    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
    {
        expires      12h;
        error_log /dev/null;
        access_log /dev/null;
    }

location \~ /(data|conf|bin|inc|vendor)/ {
deny all;
}

    access_log  /www/wwwlogs/www.mike028.com.log;
    error_log  /www/wwwlogs/www.mike028.com.error.log;

}
```

Can anyone give some advices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression locations are evaluated in order, and stop when a match is found. See [`location` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) documentation.

You have placed your new regular expression location at the end of the server block, so **any** matching regular expression location blocks occurring before it, will cause it to be ignored. For example, the `location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$` block.

You should move this new block to near the start of the location blocks, with the other blocks that also deny access.